# How to Refresh RecyclerView display when I hit my own API

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

so I make social media app using RecyclerView, it has like button and like counter
When MainActivity load OnCreate it will hit "http//test/getLikeCounter" to display like counter in my RecyclerView
but when I click like button,  it will hit my own API "http//test/setLikeCounter" and adding the counter in my database, but because it's not loading OnCreate method again it, so it's doesn't add my Like Counter in My RecyclerView, how should I do to Refresh my RecyclerView dynamically when I click Like Button?

this is getLikeCounter RecyclerView

```
public void createDummyData1UPDATE(int ReceivedDummyUrutan, int ReceivedTotalThread, String ReceivedDummyIDContent, String ReceivedDummyTitle, String ReceivedDummyPublishTime, String ReceivedDummyImageOri, String ReceivedDummyShortDescription, int ReceivedDummySeen, int ReceivedDummyComment, int ReceivedDummyLike, int ReceivedDummyisComment, int ReceivedDummyisLike, int ReceivedDummyisBookmark) {
    modelSingleHotTrendingNews.add(new ModelSingleHotTrendingNews(ReceivedDummyIDContent, ReceivedDummyTitle, ReceivedDummyPublishTime, ReceivedDummyImageOri, ReceivedDummyShortDescription, ReceivedDummySeen, ReceivedDummyComment, ReceivedDummyLike, ReceivedDummyisComment, ReceivedDummyisLike, ReceivedDummyisBookmark,"x53535", "No Error"));

    if(ReceivedDummyUrutan ==  ReceivedTotalThread-1){
        ModelSectionHotTrendingNews modelSectionHotTrendingNewsX = new ModelSectionHotTrendingNews();
        modelSectionHotTrendingNewsX.setHeaderTitle("TRENDING NEWS");
        modelSectionHotTrendingNewsX.setAllItemsInSection(modelSingleHotTrendingNews);
        modelSectionHotTrendingNews.add(modelSectionHotTrendingNewsX);

        RecyclerViewSingleHotTrendingNews = v.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView_Single_HotTrendingNews);
        RecyclerViewSingleHotTrendingNews.setHasFixedSize(true);
        adapterSectionHotTrendingNews = new AdapterSectionHotTrendingNews(getActivity(), modelSectionHotTrendingNews, listenerHotTrendingNews);
        RecyclerViewSingleHotTrendingNews.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        RecyclerViewSingleHotTrendingNews.setAdapter(adapterSectionHotTrendingNews);
        //Optimized
        RecyclerViewSingleHotLatestNews.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerViewSingleHotLatestNews.setItemViewCacheSize(20);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use Observe LiveData objects to listen your data changed?
ref: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#observe_livedata_objects

When you call api successfully I using LiveData to observe data change to refresh UI

```
// Create the observer which updates the UI.
    val nameObserver = Observer<String> { newName ->
        // Update the UI, in this case is your recyclerview
    }

    // Observe the LiveData, passing in this activity as the LifecycleOwner and the observer.
    model.currentName.observe(this, nameObserver)
```

Comment: I don't know how to implement it